# Is $M=[0,1)$ with $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y|\}$ a complete metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $M=[0,1)$. For $x,y\in M$, define

$$d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y|\}.$$

Then it can be shown that $d$ is a metric on $M$. Positive definiteness and symmetry are easy to show. The frustrating part is to prove the triangle inequality which is done in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221622/prove-the-triangle-inequality-for-dx-y-minx%E2%88%92y-1%E2%88%92x%E2%88%92y).

> Is this metric space $(M, d)$ complete?

I was thinking to find a counter example but I couldn't find any. Also, I cannot prove that it is complete!

There is a comment under [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221622/prove-the-triangle-inequality-for-dx-y-minx%E2%88%92y-1%E2%88%92x%E2%88%92y) which says

> This is the distance induced by the canonical mapping of the unit interval $[0,1)$ to the unit circle $S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Can someone elaborate on this?

Here are some of my observations.

1. For this metric we have,

$$d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
|x-y|, & 0\le|x-y|<\frac{1}{2}\\
1-|x-y|, & \frac{1}{2} \le |x-y| < 1
\end{cases}.
$$

2. The following properties are valid.

$$
\begin{array}{l}
& d(x,y) \le |x-y|, \\
& d(x,y) \le 1-|x-y|, \\
& d(x,y) \le \frac{1}{2}.
\end{array}
$$

3. A sequence which is Cauchy/Convergent with respect to $|.|$ is Cauchy/Convergent with respect to $d$. But the converse is not true. See the below example.
4. The sequence
   $$
   a_n=
   \begin{cases}
   1-\frac{1}{n},&\quad n \text{ is even} \\
   \frac{1}{n},&\quad n \text{ is odd}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is not Cauchy with respect to $|.|$ but it is Cauchy with respect to $d$. It is not convergent with respect to $|.|$ but it is convergent to $0$ in $M$ with respect to $d$!
5. If we try to add $\{1\}$ to $M$ then $d$ loses its definiteness property on $M\cup\{1\}$ and won't be a metric on $M\cup\{1\}$ anymore! The reason is that $d(1,0)=0$ but $1\ne 0$.

Comment: If you cannot find a counterexample, then instead try to show that a Cauchy sequence in the space is convergent.

Comment: @Math1000: I cannot do that either! :)

Comment: Re: Your comment to my deleted incorrect A. Speaking strictly, a topological space is a pair $(X,T)$ where $T$ is a topology on $X.$ A metric space is a triplet $(X,T,d)$ where $d$ is a metric on $X$ and the set of open d-balls in $X$ is a base (basis) for $T.$ And then we say $d$ generates $T.$ And $d$ is complete iff $(X,d)$ is complete. It is usually assumed that $(X,d)$ means the metric space $(X,T,d)$...... If $(X,T)$ is a top'l space such that $(X,T,d)$ is a metric space for some $d$, we say $(X,T)$ is metrizable and that $d$ is a metric for $(X,T)$.... (continued)...

Comment: ...(continued)... If $(X,T)$ is metrizable and $X$ has more then one member, then there are many metrics on $X$ that generate $T$, that is, many metrics for $(X,T)$.... If $(X,T)$ is compact and metrizable then every metric $d$ that generates $T$ is a complete metric, which is easy to show. The converse is true but quite hard: If $(X,T)$ is metrizable but not compact, there exists an incomplete metric for $(X,T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric space $S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is formally defined as $\{ \overline{x} \, \colon x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $\overline{x} := \{x+n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. For instance, one element of $S^1$ is $\overline{1.5} = \{\dots, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, \dots\}$. It is usually referred to as the torus and is endowed with the following distance $\delta$ :

Let $\delta(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ be the smallest distance (in $\mathbb{R}$) between an element of $\bar{x}$ and an element of $\bar{y}$. For instance, one can check that $\delta(\overline{1.5}, \overline{3.4}) = 0.1$.

Now you can show that there is an homeomorphism between $(M,d)$ and $(S^1,\delta)$.

More precisely, show that $\delta(\overline{x},\overline{y}) = d(x,y)$ whenever $x,y \in M$. Then any Cauchy sequence in $M$ can be mapped to a Cauchy sequence in $S^1$, and hence converges. That proves that $(M,d)$ is complete.

**Side Note**: They are also homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{U}, \lvert \cdot \rvert)$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is the set of complex numbers with modulus $1$, and that's why $S^1$ is called "the unit circle" in the comment.

**A Direct Approach**: Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $(M,d)$. If $\limsup x_n < 1$, show that $(x_n)$ converges to this limit in $(M,d)$. Else, we have $\limsup x_n = 1$. Hence, there is a subsequence $x_{\phi(n)}$ that converges in the metric space $([0,1],|.|)$ to $1$. Show that $x_{\phi(n)}$ converges to $0$ in $(M,d)$. Deduce that $x_n$ actually converges to $0$ in $(M,d)$.

Comment: You are right, one should also notice that the (natural) homeomorphism is uniformly continuous. I should edit my answer.

Comment: I have two more questions. 1. What is the homeomorphism between $(M,d)$ and $(\mathbb{U},|.|)$. 2. Can you think of a direct approach (not using homeomorphisms) to show that $(M,d)$ is complete?

Comment: 1. The homeomorphism between $(M,d)$ and $(\mathbb{U},\lvert\cdot \rvert)$ is given by $x\mapsto e^{2i\pi x}$. Of course, you should prove that it is actually a homeomorphism.

Comment: 2. Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $(M,d)$. If $\lim \sup x_n <1$, show that $(x_n)$ converges to this limit in $(M,d)$. Else, we have $\lim\sup x_n =1$. Hence there is a subsequence $(x_{\phi(n)})$ that converges (w.r.t to absolute value) to $1$. Show that $(x_{\phi(n)})$ converges (w.r.t to $d$) to $0$. Deduce that $(x_n)$ actually converges to $0$.

Comment: Is it the same as saying that $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x\mapsto(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, but be careful about the image : you should consider $f \colon [0,1) \to \{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2 \colon x^2+y^2=1\}$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the image. I remember that in Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*, he says that this map is not a homeomorphism. Indeed, it is a continuous bijection whose inverse is not continuous!

Comment: It depends entirely on the distance you're using on the preimage : what you just said is correct about $[0,1)$ endowed with $\lvert \cdot \rvert$, but not endowed with $d$ !

Comment: Well said. :) Thanks for the discussion. So, more precisely, $(M, d)$ is homeomorphic to $(S^1, |.|)$ with $S^1$ being the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: By the way, I think that showing the map that we introduced is indeed a homeomorphism is as hard as writing a direct proof! :)