Triangle inequality property of a metric
A few years ago (around 8) I solved the following question:

Given the metric $d_*(x,y) = \text{min}(|x-y|, 1-|x-y|)$ in $X = [0,1)$, prove it holds the triangle inequality property.

I solved it as follows:
$\begin{align*}d_*(x,z) &= \min  \{ d(x,z), 1 - d(x,z) \} \\&\leq \min  \{ d(x,y) + d(y,z), 1 - d(x,z) \} \\ &\leq  \min  \{ d(x,y), 1 - d(x,z) \}  + \min  \{ d(y,z), 1 - d(x,z) \} \\ &\color{blue}{\,\,\leq \min  \{ d(x,y), 1 - (d(x,y) - d(y,z)) \} + \min  \{ d(y,z), 1 -(d(y,z) - d(x,y))  \}} \\& \color{blue}{\,\, \leq \min  \{ d(x,y), 1 - d(x,y)  \} + \min  \{ d(y,z), 1 - d(y,z)  \}} = d_* (x,y) + d_* (y,z)  \end{align*}$
But I can't recall how I did go from the third inequality to the fourth one (marked in blue). In fact, I would say its wrong, since $1 - (d(x,y) - d(y,z)) \geq 1 - d(x,y)$

Are you sure that this is the correct proof? It is obvious that $1-(d(x, y)-d(y, z)) \geq 1-d(x, y)$. If $\min {d(x, y), 1-(d(x, y)-d(y, z))} = 1-(d(x, y)-d(y, z))$, then $\min {d(x, y), 1-d(x, y)} = 1-d(x, y)$. But this will imply $\min {d(x, y), 1-(d(x, y)-d(y, z))} \geq \min {d(x, y), 1-d(x, y)}$. I think the proof for this question cannot be done in this way. You can see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1222153/1287431

No sorry, I already know alternative proofs. I just want to remember or finish mine. It looks like either i didnt write it correctly in the past or either I messed it up in the te third inequality.
